# How to get a stack trace from FastMM

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, fastmm

I've noticed in the following post that you can get a stack trace out of FastMM to show what appears to be where an object was allocated:

[How to track down tricky memory leak with fastMM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271850/)

I can't find any information on how to enable this in Delphi 2009, though.

I have set `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` to true so I get the basic report, but how do I get the stack trace report?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The internal Delphi version of FastMM doesn't support stack traces.

If you want to log the memory leak stack traces, you have to:

- download the full version of the [FastMM library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/)
- include it as the *first unit* in your project:

  ```
  program YourProject;

  uses
    FastMM4, // <--
    SysUtils,
    Forms,
    ...
  ```
- enable the `FullDebugMode` option in `FastMM4Options.inc`
- set *Map file* to *Detailed* in the linking project options (the `FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll` processes the `.map` file)
- add the `FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll` in your binary (or Windows `System32`) directory

Comment: FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll can also be stored in the Windows system directory.

Comment: on my 64 bit windows I had to copy it to: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: I have done all of the above, but still not working for me. I use Delphi XE4  so symbol reference info is "reference info". Everything enabled in debugging.

Answer (score 7):

You may also want to check out Jeremy North's FastMM4 Option setting program.  It's just a bit easier than editing the inc FastMM4Options.inc file directly.  Here's the link:

[FastMM4 Options Interface Blog Post](http://jedqc.blogspot.com/2007/07/new-fastmm4-options-interface.html)

Answer (score 5):

In addition, Francois Gaillard presented on CodeRage II a session called Fighting Memory Leaks for Dummies and deals specifically with FastMM. It is listed under the CodeRage II replays at thursday, November 29, 2007, 9.45am - 10:45am.

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37498

Regards,
Erwin

Answer (score 3):

You can also see [this](http://eurekalog.blogspot.ru/2009/05/catching-memory-leaks_26.html) and [this](http://eurekalog.blogspot.ru/2010/02/catching-memory-leaks-redux_16.html) for more detailed description, than ulrichb's reply.

And [don't forget to enable "Use Debug DCUs" option](http://eurekalog.blogspot.ru/2009/04/optimal-project-settings_21.html) ;)

Comment: "Use Debug DCUs" is optional and not directly related to FastMM's debugging capabilities of your OWN source code.