# Memory Leak on Delphi Form Controlls

Tags: forms, delphi, memory-leaks, vcl, fastmm

I've found a strange memory leak in a project that I've been newly assigned to.

On terminating, the program displays the following FastMM4 error message.

[image: FastMM4 Error]

The project uses [BusinessSkinForm](http://www.almdev.com/prods/bsf/scs.htm)

`TbsaSpeedButtonSubClass` is from the third party `BusinessSkinForm` library, however the speed buttons on that form appear to be regular VCL form controls.

When I add another speed button to the form,

[image: speedButton]

I now have **25** instances of `TbsaSpeedButtonSubClass` that leak instead of 24.

Which leads me to think that the leak is due to the `TSpeedButton`. 
However, this seems strange to me since I would expect form components to be automatically freed by the form upon destruction.

Perhaps `BusinessSkinForm` does something unusual to the form which results in a leak...

I'm not sure how to get rid of this leak

**EDIT**

Thanks to KenWhite I have a memory leak report from FastMM4

[Here it is on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sXgGwPYB)

**EDIT**

As shown in the stack trace, the problem can be traced to a `TMUSICMainForm.SkinForm_OnCreate(SkinForm: TForm);`

The problem seems to be related to a `BSA: TbsaSkinAdapter`

If I comment out the line `BSA.ChangeSkinData;`

the leak is no longer present.

**EDIT**

Here is the important part of the stack trace

> --------------------------------2015/11/24 12:16:03-------------------------------- A memory block has been
>   leaked. The size is: 308
>
> This block was allocated by thread 0x1258, and the stack trace (return
>   addresses) at the time was: 402AB6 [madZip][madZip][@GetMem] 4035F9
>   [madCrypt][madCrypt][TObject.NewInstance] 4039CA
>   [madCrypt][madCrypt][@ClassCreate] 67438A
>   [bsaadapter.pas][bsaadapter][TbsaSpeedButtonSubclass.Create][11537]
>   66137E [bsaadapter.pas][bsaadapter][TbsaHook.SetControl][2637] 403A1E
>   [madCrypt][madCrypt][@AfterConstruction] 665BFB
>   [bsaadapter.pas][bsaadapter][TbsaSkinManager.DoControlMessage][4898]
>   6615B7
>   [bsaadapter.pas][bsaadapter][TbsaHookCollection.AddControl][2760]
>   404ACB [madExcept][madExcept][@LStrSetLength] 662A0E
>   [bsaadapter.pas][bsaadapter][TbsaSkinManager.CollectSpeedButton][3544]
>   92C81D
>   [Sources\uMainForm.pas][uMainForm][TMUSICMainForm.SkinForm_OnCreate][4778]
>
> The block is currently used for an object of class:
>   TbsaSpeedButtonSubclass
>
> The allocation number is: 475863
>
> Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7E8A7670:
>   64 C9 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 68 F3 48 00 50 96 97
>   7E B8 5E 74 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B8 D1 74 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 d  É  e  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  h  ó  H  .  P
>   –  —  ~  ¸  ^  t  ~  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
>   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  . 
>   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
>   .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
>   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
>   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ¸  Ñ  t  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  . 
>   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
>   .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
>   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
>   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .

**EDIT**

I've managed to create a minimum working example of the memory leak.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  BusinessSkinForm, bsaadapter, Buttons
  ;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  BSF: TbsBusinessSkinForm;
  BSA: TbsaSkinAdapter;
begin
    BSF := TbsBusinessSkinForm.Create(Self);

    BSF.BorderIcons:=[biMinimize,biMaximize];

    BSA := TbsaSkinAdapter.Create(Self);

    BSA.AdapterType := bsaUseClasses;

    BSA.ChangeSkinData;
end;

end.
```

I've found that even if I comment out seemingly innocent looking lines like 
`BSF.BorderIcons:=[biMinimize,biMaximize];` or `BSA.AdapterType := bsaUseClasses;`
 then the memory leak disappears.

Note my delphi form in this example contains 1 `TSpeedButton`

[image: minimal bug]

**EDIT**

I should also add that I'm using windows 7 (64bit), 6GB ram, delphi 5, Business Skin version 4.70

**EDIT**

the `bsaadapter` unit in BusinessSkinForm contains a function

```
procedure TbsaSkinManager.DoUnhook(Control: TControl; Handle: HWnd);
var
  i: integer;
  SC: TbsaSubclass;
  R: TRect;
begin
  if FUnhooking then Exit;

  if FUnhookedList = nil then
  begin
    FUnhooking := true;
    Exit;
  end;

  FUnhooking := true;
  try
    for i := FHandleList.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      SC := TbsaSubclass(FHandleList[i]);

      if (Handle <> 0) and (SC.Handle = Handle) then
      begin
        R := Rect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
        PostMessage(Handle, WM_NCPAINT, 0, 0);
        InvalidateRect(Handle, @R, false);
        FHandleList.Delete(i);
        SC.Free;
      end;

      if (Control <> nil) and (SC.Control = Control) then
      begin
        FHandleList.Delete(i);
        SC.FControl := nil;
        if not (Control is TGraphicControl) then
          SC.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FUnhooking := false;
  end;
end;
```

It seems that speed buttons do not get freed because they are instances of `TGraphicControl`

> if not (Control is TGraphicControl) then
>       SC.Free;

While a regular `TButton` will get freed

Comment: You can start by following the instructions in the *Note* in the dialog you posted, which will lead you to specific code. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1130506/62576) for details.

Comment: I added `{$DEFINE FullDebugMode}` to my `dpr` file. No output file was produced.

Comment: There's more to it than that - did you read the answer I linked above?

Comment: @KenWhite Yep, `FastMM4Options.inc` included, FastMM4 is first in uses, set Map file to Detailed, FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll is in directory

Comment: Have you done a full build, rather than a compile?

Comment: Did you also edit the `FastMMOptions.inc` file to set the appropriate defines? Did you build your project (not *compile*)?

Comment: @KenWhite I think rebuilding it did the trick

Comment: So look at the stack trace. The numbers in `[]` toward the right side indicate line numbers. You can see exactly where the class in question is used, which indicates that `TSpeedButton` has been affected by the skin library code (looks like it's in `bsadapter.pas`, from a quick glance). Use the source to figure out where the leak is occurring. FastMM is telling you *exactly* where to look.

Comment: You should include your memory leak report directly in your question, not in an off-site link which might not be valid a year from now.

Comment: I've tried this using the `TButton` and it does not leak, it only leaks when using `TSpeedButton`. I wonder if this indicates a leak/bug in the BusinessSkinForm library.

Comment: There's no code here. There's a defect somewhere. Look in the code.

Comment: Yea, the whole code base would be too big to post, but I think the important part of it is the call to ChangeSkinData since removing this line of code eliminates the leak. I think the problem is related to how BusinessSkinForm uses the TSpeedButton control.

Comment: So look in the code. You know which class is being leaked. Work out why the code creates instances of that class but does not destroy them.

Comment: Your continued edits are not helping, because you're simply repeating the same information. I've already pointed out that the TSpeedButton is being modified by code in `TbsaSpeedButtonSubclass`, so any change you make to the property of a `TSpeedButton` is meaningless - the functionality in the subclass is affecting the behavior. David and I have both told you **precisely** what you need to do to figure out what the issue is, and none of your edits address doing so. We don't have the relevant component in order to debug it for  you - **you** need to **debug the code** based on the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see here there are a number of ways which I can proceed from here.

1. Submit a fix to BusinessSkinForm to handle the speed button
2. Live with using a work around
   ie: `BSA.AdapterType := bsaUseNames;` instead of `BSA.AdapterType := bsaUseClasses;`
3. Replace the speed buttons with the regular `TButton`.

Comment: I'll leave this one open for a while in case anyone else has some other suggestions. Thanks for all the help :)